# Duration comparison in prolog

Tags: prolog, owl, swi-prolog, xmlschema

I made an OWL ontology with some xsd:duration datatype. Then I converted it into prolog facts using Thea.

I have the following xsd:duration structure [PnYnMnDTnHnMnS](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_date.asp). How can I write prolog rules to compare two durations, in order to establish which one is greater?

When I retrieve data from my prolog facts, it has this form:

`literal(type('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#duration', Value))`

I managed to extract Value using:

```
extractDuration(Literal, Result):-arg(1,Literal,Out1),arg(2,Out1,Result).
```

Which leads to (for example):

```
'P5D', 'PT10H', or 'P3DT15H32M'
```

Still have no idea how to compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This representation is not going to be easy. Why not something more conventional?

Ideally, you would represent *internally* a duration as seconds (a float) (depends what granularity you think you need). Then it is trivial to compare or calculate. You can use a date/time library to convert that to a human-readable format.

Alternatively, you can use something like `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`. This compares correctly (so, `0001-12-30T00:00:00` is smaller than `0002-00-00T00:00:00`); but this has the problem that you always have to normalize it and this is not at all trivial.

Comment: Yeah, I was just hoping there was something of conventional in prolog for the xsd:duration datatype. But now I think, as you suggested, that to put an integer that indicates a time unit is the easiest way to go on. Thank you.